# The double cone is not a surface.

Tags: geometry, analysis, algebraic-geometry, differential-geometry, manifolds

My question is that

A double cone ( also named as "circular cone") is not a surface.

I know its reason. But I cannot show this mathematically.

---

Suppose $\sigma : U \to S\cap W$ Is a surface patch.

Because the vertex $(0,0,0,)$ is a problem,  S is not a surface.

I can see it. But I cannot express it in the mathematical way.

When I remove the vertex point $(0,0,0)$, the double cone is a surface.

Please can someone show/write these mathematically?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How can we show the cone $x^2 +y^2 = z^2$ is not a smooth manifold?](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489677/how-can-we-show-the-cone-x2-y2-z2-is-not-a-smooth-manifold)

Comment: But I dont ask this is not a smooth manifold. I cannot show this is not a surface. Similar but not the same @MichaelHoppe

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you remove a point from an open subset in $\mathbb{R}^2$, it remains connected. A surface patch around the vertex has to give a homeomorphism to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. However, any open neighborhood of the vertex has the property that if you remove the vertex it becomes disconnected. Thus it cannot be homeomorphic to a subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Comment: Then, I define an open set $U=\Bbb R^2 /\{(0,0)\}$. And $\sigma : U \to \Bbb R^3$  Such that $\sigma(u,v)=(u,v,- or + \sqrt{u^2+v^2})$

Comment: I do not really know how to express my ideas for this proof.

Comment: Can you help me more explicitly?

Comment: Hmm, is this answer enough to get successful point for a homework? I know all these. But I cannot express properly. So i have asked Dear I.Solomon.

Answer (score 2):

Note that if S where to be a regular surface, then it would be, in an open nhood of $(0,0,0)$ in $S$, the graph of differentiable function of the form: $x=f(y,z)$, $y=g(x,z)$ or $z=h(x,y)$. But that obviously cannot be the case, once the projections of S onto the coordinate planes aren't injective.

Comment: for future readers, this is proposition 2.23 in Ros-Montiel Curves and Surfaces (the explanation comes from lemma 2.21)