# Implicit representations of a regular surface.

Tags: differential-geometry

Suppose that $\mathcal{S}$ is a regular surface and $f(x,y,z)=0$ is an implicit representation of this surface in a neighbourhood $V$.  Can it be shown in general that at any point of $V\cap\mathcal{S}$, one of $\partial f/ \partial x$, $\partial f/ \partial y$ or $\partial f/\partial z$ is non zero?

I can show that if $\mathcal{S}$ is a regular surface, $\mathcal{S}$ can be locally represented as the graph of a function of the form $x = h(y,z)$ (possibly relabelling axes), which is what the implicit function theorem would give me when applied to $f$ if $f$ had a non partial derivative. I can also show that if $f(x,y,z)$ is smooth (has derivatives of all orders) and $0$ is a regular value of $f$, then $f^{-1}(0)$ defines a regular surface.  However given an arbitrary implicit representation of $\mathcal{S}$, I am not sure how to go about showing the existence of a non zero partial derivative at any point, as the implicit function theorem says nothing about $f$ if all its partial derivatives are zero, and all my attempts at taking various partial derivatives and moving them around do not give any decisive information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A normal vector to the tangent plane at any regular point is the gradient vector $\nabla f$: if it's a zero-vector there is no tangent plane and the point cannot be called regular.

More precisely, you may refer for example to [Introduction to Smooth Manifolds, John M. Lee](http://books.google.co.nz/books?id=eqfgZtjQceYC&pg=PA182&lpg=PA182&dq=regular+point+manifold&source=bl&ots=xZ3_GbCZG3&sig=gmEhynmsXbr9WKckGJkceYW2wUA&hl=en&sa=X&ei=Uzc_VKKzPKHGmQXV74GwCA&ved=0CDwQ6AEwBA#v=onepage&q=regular%20point%20manifold&f=false): a point $p$ is regular of $f$ if $Df_p=df(x,y,z)=f_xdx+f_ydy+f_zdz$ is surjective  onto $T_p\mathbb{R}=\mathbb{R}$ which it cannot be if it's zero.

Comment: Does a point $p$ not being regular with respect to the representation $f$ imply that the surface is not regular? This is the bit I find tricky. Regularity of the surface means that at each point, there is _some_ surface patch in which the point is regular, but not necessarily any particular surface patch.

Comment: yes, it does.  Once we found a singular point p on the surface defined by an implicit function, no other representation or parametrization can make the point regular. Think of a [cone](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489677/how-can-we-show-the-cone-x2-y2-z2-is-not-a-smooth-manifold): there is no tangent plane at p=0 regardless.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what your question is. But I will give some comments.

Even if $f(x, y, z)$ had not non zero partial derivative at any point then $f^2$ definitely do. Though it defines the same surface.

Also you did not specify whether point of V is your surface. If not, then false (even if they are not zero on surface). For exapmle let $V$ be all $\mathbb{R}^3$ and condsider equation $x^2 = 1$. Then if $x=0$ then all derivatives are zero.

If you assume that partial are not zero at some point, so they are in sufficiently small neighborhood.

Comment: Sorry, I was being sloppy - I meant a point in $V$ and on the surface.  I am not sure I follow your first point however - $\partial/\partial x (f(x,y,z))^2 = 2f(x,y,z)f_x$, which is zero if $f$ has zero partial derivatives.

Comment: About my first point. This is exactly what I mean. $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x} f^2 = \frac{\partial }{\partial y} f^2 = \frac{\partial }{\partial z} f^2 = 0$$
Is not it the answer on your question? Fact which you tried to prove is false.

Comment: Sorry, I still do not follow your argument.  I think you have shown that, given $f$, there is always another function, $f^2$, which has partial derivatives which are zero.  But I don't see how this implies that $f$ has zero partial derivatives.