# Proving that the cone is not a smooth manifold

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology

> Show that the cone given by $C = \{(x, y, z) \in \mathbb{R}^3 \mid z = \sqrt{x^2 + y^2}\}$ is not a smooth manifold

In the definition I'm using of a smooth manifold, each point $x \in M \subseteq \mathbb{R}^k$ (where $M$ inherits the subspace topology from $\mathbb{R}^k$ with the usual topology) has a neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $M$ such that $U$ is diffeomorphic to some open set of $\mathbb{R}^n$ for some $n > 0$. (This is the definition I'm using from Guillemin and Pollack's *Differential Topology* book)

Now to prove that $C$ is not a smooth manifold I'd have to show that there exists a point $x \in C$ such that any neighborhood $U$ of $x$ in $C$ is not diffeomorphic to any open set of $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Now I recall reading that $C$ is a topological $2$-manifold, hence each point of $C$ would have a neighborhood in $C$ homeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. So the smoothness of the homeomorphism must fail at some point in $C$.

It seems that smoothness will fail at $x = 0 \in C$. I want to find out how to rigorously prove this.

I'm guessing the proof outline will go something like this;

---

*Proof Outline:* Let $U$ be a neighbourhood of $0$ in $C$ and suppose that there existed a diffeomorphism $f : U \to \widehat{U}$ where $\widehat{U}$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. We show that this results in a  contradiction, hence it will follow that no neighborhood of $0$ in $C$ is diffeomorphic to an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ and hence $C$ consequently will not be a smooth manifold.

---

However since I've picked an arbitrary diffeomorphism $f$, I don't know of any way to go about finding a contradiction.

How can I go about proving this?

Also in my proof outline I wrote above, the proof really only shows that $C$ is not a smooth $2$-manifold, wouldn't I need to show that $C$ is not a smooth manifold for any $n > 0$? In that case I'm guessing that $C$ wouldn't even be a topological manifold for any $n \neq 2$.

Comment: If you remove the origin the space is disconnected. No open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$  has this property.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus How do you know that $C \setminus \{0\}$ is disconnected? Can you give me two open sets $U, V$ in $C$ such that $U \cup V = C \setminus \{0\}$?

Comment: Yeah $z<0$ and $z>0$.

Comment: The partial derivatives in any neighborhood of the origin don't exist because the right and left hand limits disagree.

Comment: @ReneSchipperus I think you're referring to the double cone, in this case  $z \not<0$ in any point of $C$

Comment: Oh yeah, ok, I see the question now.

Comment: @JohnDouma Could you elaborate a bit please and give a more formal answer if possible?

Comment: The partial derivative with respect to $x$ at the origin is equivalent to the derivative of the absolute value function. Use the definition of derivative. The right hand limit will be $1$ and the left hand limit will be $-1$.

Comment: @JohnDouma Okay but in that case are you not assuming a specific parameterization/diffeomorphism of $C$ at $x = 0$?

Comment: Yes. Take a look at https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/489677/how-can-we-show-the-cone-x2-y2-z2-is-not-a-smooth-manifold

Comment: @JohnDouma The definition used in the OP of that question is different however and moreover the set $C$ in that question is not the same as the set $C$ in this question, can you tell me if possible what specific property of $f$ in my question yields a contradiction? Or why choosing a specific parametrization/diffeomorphism of a neighbourhood $U$ of $0$ in $C$ and showing that the diffeomorphism/parametrization is not smooth allows us to conclude that $C$ is not a smooth $2$-manifold?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Assume $f:U\to C$ is a diffeomorphism of $U\subseteq \mathbb{R}^2$ open onto a nbd of $0$. Let $p:C\to \mathbb{R}^2$ the projection onto the $x,y$ plane then $p\circ f$ is a diffeomorphism and has an inverse by the inverse function theorem. Call it $g$.  Then $f\circ g(x,y)=(x,y,\sqrt{x^2+y^2})$ is differentiable, a contradiction.

Although, I am not happy with this answer, as the real meaning of the question is to show that the cone in not the IMBEDDING of a manifold into three space. In fact the cone as a topological space is homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$ which is a smooth manifold.

Comment: why $p\circ f$ is a diffeomorphism and isnt $f\circ g(x,y)=p^{-1}$